# How can access individual number of an array element in C?

Tags: c

If I have some array element, how can I get  individual numbers from the array element `buffer[0]`?

For example, suppose I have `buffer[0]=0x0605040302`, I'd like to first extract 2, then 0, then 6, etc.

Comment: You might want to edit your post. Use blockquote instead of code.

Also what data type is buffer?

Comment: Im surprised this question is upvoted.

Comment: If i say buffer is unsigned long long int.How would you extract single digit from the array element.

Comment: @Thej, you can extract single element by masking other elements.

Comment: I edited your question a bit for formatting and clarity, but ultimately I think you need to come up with a better title and refine your question a bit. You're looking for *masking*, and the fact the number is stored in an array has nothing to do with your actual question.

Comment: @Praveen S:Thanks.But can you give me an example so that i can understand more clearly.sry for inconvenience though.I am just learning

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The array element content is ONE number. You are trying to extract A DIGIT out of it. Look for masking and shifting - the & and >> operators.

**EDIT:**

A mask is a string of "0"s and "1"s that let you isolate bits of interest out of a number. A mask containing the hex digit 0xF is used to isolate individual hex digits in a number. For example:

`num        = 0x4321 (= 0100_0011_0010_0001)`
`mask       = 0x00f0 (= 0000_0000_1111_0000)`
`num & mask = 0x0020 (= 0000_0000_0010_0000)`

Shifting a number effectively brings the required bit to a required position in a number. So, shifting a number to the right by n positions will bring bit #n to place #0.

`num      = 0x4321 (= 0100_0101_0010_0001)`
`num >> 8 = 0x0043 (= 0000_0000_0100_0011)`

Combine the two operations and you have your extracted digit!